# how to change the H2 database console port number specified by Liquibase example?

Tags: port, h2, liquibase

The `Liquibase` install comes with an examples directory you can use to learn about different commands.  The examples use a `H2` database with a web console on port 9090.  Unfortunately port 9090 is not available.

I'm asking how can I change the web-conole port used with the example `H2` database started by the script:

- `start-h2`

The port appears to be specified by the Liquibase `liquibase.example.StartH2Main` module itself.  H2 doesn't seem influenced by changes to: `$HOME/.h2.server.properties` ...

```
java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar:liquibase.jar liquibase.example.StartH2Main
Starting Example H2 Database...
NOTE: The database does not persist data, so stopping and restarting this process will reset it back to a blank database

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at liquibase.example.StartH2Main.startTcpServer(StartH2Main.java:74)
    at liquibase.example.StartH2Main.main(StartH2Main.java:28)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Exception opening port "9090" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" [90061-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createServerSocketTry(NetUtils.java:180)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createServerSocket(NetUtils.java:146)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.start(TcpServer.java:245)
    at org.h2.tools.Server.start(Server.java:511)
```

I'm hoping there's a `.properties` file setting or command line option that will change the web-console port number `H2` to use.

Comment: Looks hard-coded: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/example/StartH2Main.java Should be simple enough to edit the example though.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ... Thanks for that, I was just about to start looking for the example source code.  I'm hoping I can run `H2` independently of the `liquibase.jar` or at least use the `liquibase.jar` on  the class path.  At least before I rebuild something.

Comment: Just need to copy-paste-edit that single example class. It's an example, it's not part of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question, taking the lead from @RobbyCornelissen recommendation, with the following updates.

1. It is completely possible to build the `StartH2Main` class.
2. Change the `dbPort` constant from `9090` to something '*available*' like 8092.

- The `StartH2Main` app loads H2 and side-steps the `.h2.server.properties` file.

3. Build a `StartH2Main.jar` for yourself.

- The `9090` is hard-coded for `StartH2Main`.
- Port `9090` is the database port, which means that all the examples must be updated to match the new port number given.

Personally I feel that anything such as a port used for a demo or tutorial should be something I can put on the command line or in a config file.  Thus, avoiding timeconsuming or inconvenient barriers to adoption.  It just makes sense.  Such things can always have a default, please allow them to be configured as well.